# How to require .html files in typescript and test using mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I'm building an application with TypeScript and webpack.
In my .ts files I have code like this:

```
let template = require('./example.component.html');
let style = require('./example.component.scss');
```

My Webpack loaders are like this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'demo/index.scss')],
    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
},
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['html-loader'],
}
```

I also have a ./test/mocha.opts file with the following content:

```
--require ts-node/register
--require ./test/css-modules-compiler.js
--recursive
--module commonjs
```

and then I execute my test:

```
mocha src/**/*.spec.ts
```

Executing the application using webpack works fine.

When I execute the test, it does not know how to load the .html file and I get the following error:

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117452
            throw new Error("Could not find file: '" + fileName + "'.");
                  ^
Error: Could not find file: '/path/to/project/src/example/example.component.html'.
```

How can I proper load the .html content file and execute my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I decided to use karma-runner to run my test and do the transpile before execute the test using mocha.

It worked well.